# C++ Macro to conditionally compile code?

Tags: c++, macros

I want to compile code conditionally based on a macro. Basically I have a macro that looks like (Simplified from the real version):

```
#if DEBUG
    #define START_BLOCK( x ) if(DebugVar(#x) \
        { char debugBuf[8192];
    #define END_BLOCK( ) printf("%s\n", debugBuf); }
#else
    #define START_BLOCK( x ) (void)0;
    #define END_BLOCK( ) (void)0;
#endif
```

The issue is that if `DEBUG` is defined you could do things like:

```
START_BLOCK( test )
     char str[] = "Test is defined";
     strcpy(debugBuf, str);
END_BLOCK( )

START_BLOCK( foo )
    char str[] = "Foo is defined";
    strcpy(debugBuf, str);
END_BLOCK( )
```

And everything works fine because each block is within it's own scope. However if DEBUG isn't defined, then you'd get a redefinition of `str` in the second block. (Well you'd also get `debugBuf` not defined but that's just a side effect of the simplified example.)

What I'd like to do is to have the #else be something like:

```
#else
    #define START_BLOCK( x ) #if 0
    #define END_BLOCK( ) #endif
#endif
```

Or some other method of not having anything between the start / end blocks be compiled. I tried the above, I also tried something along the lines of:

```
#else
    #define NULLMACRO( ... ) (void)0
    #define START_BLOCK( x ) NULLMACRO(
    #define END_BLOCK( ) )
#endif
```

without any luck.

Is there a way for this to work? One thought that just occurred to me is that I could maybe abuse the optimizing compiler and use:

```
#else
    #define START_BLOCK( x ) if(0){
    #define END_BLOCK( ) }
#endif
```

And trust that it will just compile out the block completely. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want conditional blocks with their own scope?

Here's a quite readable solution that relies on the compiler to optimize it away:

```
#define DEBUG 1

if (DEBUG) {
    // ...
}
```

And here is one that is preprocessor-only:

```
#define DEBUG 1

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define IFDEBUG(x) {x}
#else
    #define IFDEBUG(x)
#endif

IFDEBUG(
    // ...
)
```

Or manually:

```
#define DEBUG 1

#ifdef DEBUG
{
    // ...
}
#endif
```

Comment: I actually originally had your middle one, the issue was how gcc vs visual studio handled var args with 0 or 1 arg, which my simplified example didn't cover, darn.

Comment: @Doug-W: who's talking about varargs?

Comment: Well, if your expression contains any commas, your middle one doesn't work. And it's pretty common for a lengthy block of code to contain commas. One way around it is varargs (which will include everything, commas and all), but varargs doesn't handle the low-argument-count case very well.

Answer (score 1):

Would:

```
#if DEBUG
    #define START_BLOCK( x ) if(DebugVar(#x) \
        { char debugBuf[8192];
    #define END_BLOCK( ) printf("%s\n", debugBuf); }
#else
    #define START_BLOCK( x ) {
    #define END_BLOCK( ) }
#endif
```

do?